# How to change from netbeans IDE to eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I'am developping an application using NetBeans, I want to know is it possible to change to eclipse? 
I'am usine JSF/primefaces ,JPA/Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want IDE interoperability then use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as your build system. It will allow you to switch between IDEs' with relative ease.